# (Java) Checking if 2 elements of a 2d array are the same with other pairs of elements. If so replacing that pair with another original pair

Tags: java, arrays

My problem is with the logic and output of the **checker** portion of the method.

After the program runs drawCard() 5 times and creates a "hand" it runs through the checker to make sure there are no replicas. If there are any replicas it "draws a new card" and replaces the matching one.

However, every time I run the program it run the program the checker portion flags and replace every "card" no matter if its an original or replica.

Also, after the logic potion is fixed, what is the easiest way to make sure that the new "card" doesn't match the existing one.

Also: each "card" is a 1d array. The kind is represented by 1-13 and the suit is 0-3

```
public static int[][] drawHand(){

    int[][] hand = new int[5][2];

    //CALLS drawCard 5 TIMES AND FILLS THE 5 SLOTS WITH "CARDS" CREATES A "HAND"
    for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {

        int[] x = drawCard();
        hand[i][0]=x[0];
        hand[i][1]=x[1];
    }
    //PRINTS OUT HAND BEFORE IT GOES THROUGH THE CHECKER
    System.out.println("BEFORE");
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        System.out.println(hand[i][0]+" "+ hand[i][1]);
    }
    //CHECKER
    for(int h=0;h<hand.length;h++) {
        for(int f=4;f>=0;f--) {

            if(hand[h][0]==hand[f][0]&&hand[h][1]==hand[f][1]){
                int[] x = drawCard();
                hand[h][0]=x[0];
                hand[h][1]=x[1];
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("AFTER");
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++) {
        System.out.println(hand[j][0]+" "+ hand[j][1]);
    }
    return hand;
}
```

Comment: When `h==f`, you are checking the card against itself, and it will, of course, match and trigger the drawing of a new card.

Answer (score 0):

Your double loop will eventually check

- card 0 against card 0,
- card 1 against card 1,
- card 2 against card 2,
- card 3 against card 3, and
- card 4 against card 4,

Of course, these will always match, and a new card will be drawn for each.  You can prevent this by adding `f !=h` to your test, like this:

```
if(f!=h && hand[h][0]==hand[f][0]&&hand[h][1]==hand[f][1]){
```

To recheck the drawn card against others, add a `do {…} while(redraw_made);` loop.  Each time through the loop, set `redraw_made` to `false`, and if a card is redrawn, set it to `true` so that the checks are performed again.